# How to set Autocomplete in MessageHandlerOptions in Azure Service Bus Options (using Net Core 3.1)

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus, azure-webjobs

I am writing a webjob using .NET Core 3.1 and my trigger looks like:

```
public async Task ProcessQueueMessage([ServiceBusTrigger("%ServiceBusProviderConfig:TopicName%", "%ServiceBusProviderConfig:TopicSubscriptionName%", Connection = "ServiceBusConnectionString")] Message message, MessageReceiver messageReceiver, TraceWriter log, TextWriter textWriter)
```

I am processing the message and calling complete / dead lettering as per the requirement in the following manner:

```
await messageReceiver.CompleteAsync(message.SystemProperties.LockToken);
await messageReceiver.DeadLetterAsync(message.SystemProperties.LockToken);
```

However, this is throwing the error:
 `The lock supplied is invalid. Either the lock expired, or the message has already been removed from the queue, or was received by a different receiver instance.`

I understand that I need to somehow set the Autocomplete in MessageHandlerOptions to false for the webjob to not automatically complete it and remove from the queue.

But I am having difficulty setting this value. I tried:

1. setting this in the appsettings.json file as follows:

   "extensions": {
   "serviceBus": {
   "messageHandlerOptions": {
   "maxConcurrentCalls": 16,
   "autoComplete": false
   }
   }
   }

But on running, it is not picking the settings from this file. I am not sure why, how can I make the settings be read from local config file?

2. I also tried creating an object for MessageHandlerOptions but it the signature is missing a required param which makes it impossible to do this. Eg:

   ```
    var messageHandlerOptions = new MessageHandlerOptions(ExceptionHandler)
    {
        AutoComplete = false,
        MaxAutoRenewDuration = new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0), // 5 minutes
        MaxConcurrentCalls = 1,
    };

   messageReceiver.RegisterMessageHandler(MessageProcessor, messageHandlerOptions);
   ```

   static async Task MessageProcessor(Message message, CancellationToken token)
   {
   await messageReceiver.CompleteAsync(message.SystemProperties.LockToken);
   }

I am unable to access `messageReceiver` within `MessageProcessor` and thats why this is not possible too.

Can anyone please suggest how I can set ServiceBusOptions in a config file to be read at runtime?

FYI, I am using the following packages:

```
1. Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus Version="4.1.3"
2. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions Version="3.0.0"
3. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus Version="3.0.0"
4. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage Version="4.0.2"
5. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Logging.ApplicationInsights Version="3.0.14"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of searching, finally found the answer. Posting it for anyone looking for the same question:

```
    services.AddServiceBus(options =>
    {
        options.ConnectionString = "ServiceBusConnectionString";
        options.MessageHandlerOptions.AutoComplete = false;
        options.PrefetchCount = 1;
        options.MessageHandlerOptions.MaxConcurrentCalls = 1;
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Last comment on https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-servicebus-extension/issues/34 helped me to get it configured with host.json