# Azure function service bus trigger set autocomplete from function level

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-functions, azureservicebus

In Azure function app I am using a service bus trigger to read messages.

```
[FunctionName("Function1")]
public static async Task<Message> Run([ServiceBusTrigger("myqueue", Connection = "queueconnection")] Message myQueueItem, MessageReceiver messageReceiver, ILogger log)
```

So there are two options of read auto complete and peek lock. I am able to control this from `host.josn` using below configurations.

```
{
"version": "2.0",
"extensions": {
    "serviceBus": {
        "messageHandlerOptions": {
            "autoComplete": false
        }
    }
 }
}
```

But if I do this in host.json this is applicable for function app and effect all the functions deployed in that function app. So I want to know if below options are possible,If yes how it can be achieved.

1. Having auto complete property in function it self where we configure ServiceBusTrigger.
2. If it can be set in function level, making it configurable by moving the property to function app Configurations.

Answer (score 2):

Default Syntax Format of Azure Functions Service Bus Trigger is like:

```cs
[FunctionName("ServiceBusQueueTriggerCSharp")] public static void Run( [ServiceBusTrigger("myqueue", Connection = "ServiceBusConnection")] ... )
```

Here `myqueue` is the **`Queue Name`** declared at the Function Level in the Azure Function.

In the same way, we have many attributes (properties) including `AutoComplete` can be used in the **`Function Level`**, that you can refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus-trigger?tabs=in-process,extensionv5&pivots=programming-language-csharp) to see the more information on Service Bus Trigger Function Level Properties and its functionality.

If the Azure Function Stack belongs to .NET Core 3.1, then configure the `AutoComplete` option manually in **`FunctionsStartup`** file, the syntax is like:

```cs
builder.Services.Configure(delegate(ServiceBusOptions options)
{
    options.MessageHandlerOptions.AutoComplete = false;
});
```

Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62821790) for more information on configuring AutoComplete option manually.

If the Azure Function Stack belongs to greater than .NET Core 3.1, then configure the `AutoComplete` option at the **`Function`** Level in the **`ServiceBusTrigger Function Class`** like:

```cs
[FunctionName("ProcessMessage")] 
public async Task Run( 
// Setting AutoComplete to true (the default) processes the message non-transactionally 
[ServiceBusTrigger("ProcessMessage", AutoCompleteMessages = true)] ServiceBusReceivedMessage message, ILogger logger, ExecutionContext executionContext) 
{ 
await endpoint.ProcessNonAtomic(message, executionContext, logger); 
}
```

> Setting AutoComplete to false processes the message transactionally

Refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus?tabs=in-process,extensionv5,extensionv3&pivots=programming-language-csharp#hostjson-settings), provides the information on (`AutoComplete`, `AutoCompleteMessages`) naming differentiation based on Function Extension Version.